# Regular exception.Any character except

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, expression

I want

Input :www.example.com/videos/video1%2Cvideo2%2Cvideo3%2Cvideo4%2C Output:www.example.com/videos/video1,video2,video3,vide4

So i need regular expression. I tried this:^videos/[%2C](in iss url rewriting pattern). But not it is not work. It said the input data to test does not match the patter.

Comment: Working in IIS. Im using asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you mentioned it as "video", whereas in your regular expression, it is mentioned as "videos". This typo might be reason for the pattern mismatch error. Please cross check.